# When does "extractWebSession" method execute in ZAP session management script

Tags: zap

Im playing with ZAP session management script and selenium script for juice shop. Im not clear at what point below method gets executed!

```
function extractWebSession(sessionWrapper) {
   // parse the authentication response
   var json = JSON.parse(sessionWrapper.getHttpMessage().getResponseBody().toString());
   var token = json.authentication.token;
   // save the authentication token
   sessionWrapper.getSession().setValue("token", token);
}
```

Initially, I didnot store token as global variable in extractWebSession. Latter I added selenium script to inject token in session storage and in extractWebSession method added line to store the token as GlobalVar. When I open browser from ZAP, as extractWebSession is not executed again, selenium script is not able to set token in session storage.

I invoked browser from ZAP and logged in manually to see if this method gets executed, but no luck.
I thought this method should executed every time when there is a call to api flagged as auth login request(https://.../rest/user/login)! Will this method get called only once per zap session ?

Could anyone please let me know when extractWebSession method gets called by ZAP ?

Answer (score 0):

ZAP automated authentication only happens by default when you run tools like the spiders or active scan as a specific user. However you can force it to be used if you use Forced User Mode.

I cover authentication with Juice Sjop in some detail in the ADDO Workshop videos on https://www.alldaydevops.com/zap-in-ten

Comment: HI Simon, I saw the ADDO workshop video. Sorry! I didnt get "However you can force it to be used if you use Forced User Mode". I edited "extractWebSession" to store the token in the globalVar - which is used by launchbrowser method in selenium script and I have forced user mode ON. When I open the juiceshop from ZAP, im not logged in. This is because "extractWebSession" is not re-executed and globalVar is not set. If I have the code to store the token in GlobalVar in "extractWebSession" at the first timei tself, everything is working as expected!